# Python question - Communicating Between Multiple Instances of the Same Application? IN WINDOWS OS

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, ipc

I have a python application that must run only one instance of it except in two particular cases. For that reason, **I'm having issues achieving the second instance of the same application to communicate** (in the way I want) **with the first instance of that application.** Let me explain in a more "practical" way:

1. I execute the program (Which is an executable that I made with Pyinstaller)
2. Everything normal at this time; the app just do what it needs to do.
3. I re-execute the executable file again. Here is where I'm having issues.

The application currently kills the second instance and works fine. **But now I want the second instance to just simply print in the console to ask me what I want to do: Either close the program** (This is kill both running instances) **or just cancel the operation** (Kill just the second instance which is not a problem because is what I have implemented right now).

I tried to run a server and a client. **When the app is executed for the first time**, it creates a simple pid (process id) file that identifies that instance of the application and then **it runs the server function**. **When I execute for second time the program**, if the pid file is detected **it runs the client function**. Then, **the client just sends a message to the server, so it can do something,** like killing itself (and the second instance will too).

I'm pretty sure this is the way to go but I'm having issues implementing this. I cannot just run in a loop the server infinitely because the program needs to continue in many other things. I tried to run the server in a different thread but I have not much experience with concurrency so, maybe that's my problem.

Here is my current main.py file. I cannot show more for some reasons, but I think this with my previous explanation is more than enough. **Pay more attention to the ** **init**, __notify(), and __server()** methods where I was thinking to implement everything.

```
import sys, time, json, logging, os
from api_handlers import team_viewer_api as tv_api
from utils.report_writter import ReportWritter
from config.schemas import BasicAppConfig
from utils.unique_pid import instance_listener
from config.gui_model.config_from_gui import get_config_from_gui
from config.arg_model.config_from_args import get_config_from_args


class ApplicationDeviceReporter:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(filename="teamViewerAppLog.log",
                            filemode="a",
                            level=logging.DEBUG,
                            format="%(levelname)s[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s",
                            datefmt="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
        self.PID_FILE = os.getcwd() + r'\pid'
        
        single_instance = instance_listener()
        is_one_instance = single_instance.detect_running_instances(self.PID_FILE)
        if not is_one_instance:
            self.__notify()
            sys.exit()
        else:
            # Should I call self.__listen() in a different thread, or run the rest of the app
            # in a different thread and just loop infinitely the __listen() method?
            pass
                    
        self.__setup_app_configuration()
        
        logging.info("Starting application...")


    def __notify(self):
        # Implement a mechanism to notify the first instance to go into standby mode
        # For example, you can write a specific file, send a signal, or use IPC
        pass
    
    
    def __listen(self):
        # Implement a mechanism to listen for notification from another instance.
        # To kill this runtime or do another thing.
        pass


    def __setup_app_configuration(self, config_params: dict = None):
        logging.info("Setting up app's configuration...")
        if not config_params:
            if len(sys.argv) == 1:
                config_params = get_config_from_gui()
            else:
                config_params = get_config_from_args()
        self.app_configuration = BasicAppConfig(device_id=config_params['device_id'],
                                                          token=config_params['token'],
                                                          run_once=config_params['run_once'],
                                                          wait_time=config_params['wait_time'])
        logging.info("Configuration has been set succesfully.")
    
    
    def run(self):

        self.report_writter = ReportWritter()
        self.teamviewer_api_interface = tv_api.TeamViewerApiInterface(
            TOKEN=self.app_configuration.token,
            DEVICE_ID=self.app_configuration.device_id,
        )

        while True:
            app_timer_start = time.perf_counter()
            logging.info(f"Getting device status...")

            # try:
            #     data_received = self.teamviewer_api_interface.get_teamviewer_data()
            # except Exception as e:
            #     time.sleep(60)
            #     continue
     
            # logging.info("Writing report files...")
            # self.report_writter.write_reports(api_results=self.teamviewer_api_interface.results)

            app_timer_finish = time.perf_counter()
            logging.info(f'Program execution performance: {round(app_timer_finish - app_timer_start, 3)} second(s)')

            if self.app_configuration.run_once:
                break

            logging.info(f"Execution finished. Waiting until next execution in {round(self.app_configuration.wait_time / 3600, 1)} hours and {round((self.app_configuration.wait_time % 3600) / 60)} minutes...")
            time.sleep(self.app_configuration.wait_time)

        logging.info("Program finished.")
        os.remove(self.PID_FILE)
        
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ApplicationDeviceReporter()
    app.run()
```